# Is it possible to create an ASP.NET role-based authentication policy for roles that will be dynamically determined at runtime?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, authorization, rbac

I need to create an RBAC handler for a .NET Core (6+) Web API.  The basic steps to accomplish this are not overly complex, however, what complicates things is that the specific role requirement will not be known until the route is called.

For example:  Suppose I have a route `/api/reports/earnings?location=[some location]`.  If a user has report permissions, but lacks permissions for a specific location, I want them to be denied access.  Likewise, if a user does have permissions for that specific report, I want them to be granted access.

Is there a way to handle this that would still be feasible using the `[Authorize]` attribute tag?
Would that change at all if there were multiple levels (such as if an user has access to regional data and the requested report location is within/outside of their region)?

The examples and demos I have read so far do not get to this level of detail, so I'm not sure where to start.  Any useful references would be appreciated, in addition answers.

Thanks!

Comment: Which kind of RBAC handler are you using(Like Azure RBAC/Google RBAC or just customed by yourself)? If you are using self-customed RBAC handler, I think you can create a Filter for the API request. You can achieve your goal in the Filter.

Comment: @XiaotianYang, It will be customized.